# What is this mysqli query supposed to be doing with the results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been asked to fix a heavily customised zen cart and it is full of queries that don't use standard zen cart practice for accessing the database. Working with zen cart I very rarely have to deal directly with mysql commands so I've had to research the various functions as I've come across them so that I can convert thee queries to ZC standard practice.
Whilst I've done most of them and they are now working efficiently and correctly, I am somewhat stumped on this one.

```
$q = mysqli_query($connect,sprintf('SELECT * FROM FENQUIRY 
WHERE ENCSUNIQUE = %d',
$FENQCON->ENCONCSUNIQUE));
$FENQUIRY = mysqli_fetch_object($q);
mysqli_free_result($q);
```

I can see that it is supposed to be collecting all rows from table 'FENQUIRY' where ENCSUNIQUE matches a value that is found earlier in the code.
It looks to me like it then writes all that data as a string?, or array? to $FENQUIRY, and then it drops the data from $q to free the memory.
Have I interpreted that correctly?

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fetches a single row from `FENQUIRY` table and [creates the object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) `$FENQUIRY` which will contain data of the fetched row.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's what I had interpreted it as. Would mysqli_fetch_object be fetching as a string or an array?

Comment: As an object, as the name of the function says. most likely as `stdClass`, and then you can access its data as e.g. `$FENQUIRY->ENCSUNIQUE` etc

Comment: Hey STEVE the clue is in the name mysqli_fetch_**OBJECT**

Comment: It actually seems like overkill given what is done with it next. If $FENQUIRY is populated do nothing, else set  $flag_insert_into_FENQUIRY = true.
Surely that could have been achieved purely using RecordCount(); 
The var $FENQUIRY is not used anywhere else in the entire code!

Comment: It is not rather a huge performance threat. I don't know how RecordCount works. I suppose that the difference between one and the other solution is neglectable.